# add only readable row to Table View in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am very new in Qt and Qt designer and I am trying to make a table that it have 3 columns and so many rows. I made a "**Table View**" in design mood of Qt creator and a "**Push Button**" for adding only readable rows to my table when I click on it.

1. how can I do it?
2. how to have a numbered table (table rows have number 1, 2, 3, ...) at last?
3. how to change width of my columns?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at QtDocs and related examples: [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html) and [QTableWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)

Comment: I saw that before. they don't tell any thing about Qt creator and design mood and only tell about codes.@Miki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not relate the design mode to my `.h` and `.cpp` source codes and I found the answer.

we need to use `ui->` before any QWidget(like Label and QTableWidget) name that we make it in design mode and we want to work with it in our source files.

an example:

```
ui->label->setFixedWidth(50);
```